# How to retrieve data with two conditions in typeorm and nestjs

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

The following class is my table

```
@Entity()
export class Comment extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    body: string

    @Column()
    createdAt: Date

    @Column()
    userId: number

    @Column()
    courseId: number


    @OneToMany(() => Comment, comment => comment.parent, { eager: true })
    children: Comment[];


    @Column({ nullable: true })
    parentId: number

    @ManyToOne(() => Comment, comment => comment.children)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'parentId' })
    parent: Comment

    @Column()
    status: CommentStatus
}
```

I want to retrieve items with `parentId` equals to null and `coureseId` equals to **45**
but It does not work, Where I'm wrong?

```
public async getCommentsByCourseId(courseId: number): Promise<Comment[]> {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('comment')
        .innerJoinAndSelect('comment.children', 'parent')
        .where("comment.parentId IS NULL")
        .andWhere("comment.courseId = :courseId", { courseId: 45 }) // this line does not work 


    const comments = await query.getMany()

    return comments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following for a dummy entity -

```
  async getRecordsByUserId(userId: number): Promise<any[]> {
      return await getRepository(DummyEntity)
      .createQueryBuilder('dummyEntity')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('dummyEntity.user', 'user')
      .where("dummyEntity.entity_id IS NULL")
      .andWhere("dummyEntity.userId = :userId", { userId: 1 })
      .getRawMany();
  }
```

It worked as expected.

Comment: is there a way using .findOne(). I am trying to get data findOne{where{condition 1, condition 2}} but it check either one of the conditions and pass me the data. but i want both those condition true.